# Should amp-custom be placed before or after amp-boilerplate

Tags: html, css, amp-html

Some of the AMP samples I have found seem to include the `amp-custom` tag [before](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fintroduction%2Fhello_world%2Fsource%2F) the `amp-boilerplate`.

```
  <style amp-custom>
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <style amp-boilerplate>.....</style>
```

While other examples show the `amp-boilerplate` [before](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-sidebar%2Fsource%2F&mode=iPhone+5) the `amp-custom`.

```
<style amp-boilerplate>
    .....
</style>
<style amp-custom>
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

If I want my page to be compliant with AMP standards, should I place `amp-custom` style tag before or after my amp-boilerplate style tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For AMP validity, the order doesn't matter. However, the order of tags inside the header can affect page load performance. The recommended order for head tags is:

1. `meta charset`, then remaining `meta` tags.
2. AMP runtime `v0.js <script>` tag (this should start downloading as soon as possible as it's render blocking).
3. `<script>` tags for other render delaying extensions (amp-experiment, amp-dynamic-css-classes)
4. `<script>` tags for remaining extensions (amp-bind, ...)
5. `<link>` tag for favicon
6. `<style amp-custom>`
7. any other tags allowed in `<head>`
8. amp boilerplate, first `style` amp-boilerplate, then `noscript`. (putting the boilerplate lasts avoids custom styles accidentally overriding the boilerplate css rules)

Please note: this is only relevant for AMPs not served via the [Google AMP Cache](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/) as the cache re-orders the head following these rules anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Comment: Thank you!  Wondering if you've got a source for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it matters which order you put them in. If you have concerns you can always run your code through [the AMP validator tool](https://validator.ampproject.org/) or throw #development=1 after your URL and check the console in your browser dev tools.

Note: after adding #development=1 you may have to refresh the page twice with dev tools open to get it to show either a success or fail message in the console.

I just tried putting amp-custom before amp-boilerplate in the AMP validator tool as well as amp-boilerplate before amp-custom and both came back as AMP valid.

I know for our company website we put it after amp-custom due to what it defines for us so that it takes precedence over any other styling.